# RAILS Send get request to onesignal using API Key RESTApi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, onesignal

Its a RESTAPI and I need to send get request to onesignal.

url = https://onesignal.com/api/v1/apps

All they have mentioned is this:

```
curl --include \
     --header "Authorization: Basic your_key_here" \
 https://onesignal.com/api/v1/apps
```

I have tried something like this:

```
def index
    url = URI.parse('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/apps?apikey=mykey')
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
      http.request(req)
    }
    puts res.body
  end
```

but this doesn't work.
The result should be in json.

I get this error:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is it giving you , what kind of error messages ?

Comment: Hey , I updated it with the error...

Comment: can you try code from my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on code from OneSignal [webpage](http://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification) your request should be:

```rb
uri = URI.parse("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/apps")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(
  uri.path,
  "Content-Type" => "application/json",
  "Authorization" => "Basic NGXXX...XXXBlNjJj"
)

response = http.request(request) 
puts response.body
```

In your case error was associated with not using `http.use_ssl = true`, but you have several other things to add, like authorization header for example.